# Casting jQuery.active from the executeJavaScript method

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Working in an inherited automation codebase.  There is a method which waits to see if jQuery has been initialized.

```
.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
                        boolean go = (Long) runJavaScript("return jQuery.active") == 0;
                        if (!go) {
                            LOGGER.debug("stalling");
                        }
                        return go;
                    }
```

Ran into an issue with jQuery not being defined.  I added a check to see if jQuery is defined and refactored the code to use a lambda expression

```
.until((Function<WebDriver, Boolean>) webDriver -> {
                    boolean go = (Boolean) runJavaScript("return !!window.jQuery && jQuery.active == 0");
                    if(!go){
                        LOGGER.debug("stalling");
                    }
                    return go;
                });
```

My question pertains to the casting of the return of `runJavaScript` which is just a custom wrapper of JavaScriptExecutor's `executeScript` method.  Initially it was built to return `jQuery.active` cast it to a `Long` and compare it to zero.  I refactored it to cast the return of `jQuery.active == 0` to a `boolean`.   Is there any value to cast to a `Long` over a `boolean` in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what the advantage would be in casting it to a long. If it's a Boolean value, why confuse that by giving it a type that has a huge range of viable values? If there is a performance benefit, I'd be surprised if it was noticeable in your test suite. In short, I would go with Boolean because there is no reason to add complexity and confusion to what is trying to be achieved.